# Are $L^p$ spaces connected?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, metric-spaces, connectedness

Just out of curiosity, are $L^p$ spaces connected? Does the connectedness depend on $p$?

Comment: Any convex set is path connected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any element $x$ is path-connected to the zero vector by a path $\gamma_x:[0,1]\to L^p, \gamma_x(t)=tx$, and this is a property that holds in any normed vector space, not just $L^p$.

Comment: normed is not needed, a topological vector space suffices. It's also true for $0 < p < 1$, which are not normable.